# Launchimage and Appicon aren't added to assets.xcassets in Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, xcode

I deleted my images.xcassets file and when I click new -> add asset catalog I get a new blue folder but nothing inside including the launchimage and appicons.

Any advice would be great.

Thx.

Comment: you can add those same way you add your images

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add it manually, like following figure(click the "**+**" button):

[image]